# Reference JS object through concatenation

Tags: javascript, object, concatenation

I am trying to call an object.

The way I am currently doing it:

```
var key = object_0
```

The way I'd like to do it

```
var key = "object_" + questionId;
```

But when calling the concatenated object_0 I do not get the object info
when I do a:

```
console.log(key)
```

Any insight would be awesome.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you could be getting properties instead of the entire object, then it's just `obj["object_" + questionId]`

Comment: If you think you need to use dynamic variables, you're probably doing something wrong. You should put all the objects into an array, and then use `questions[questionId]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: global scope + brackets.

```
window['object_'+questionId] = 'foo';
console.log(window['object_'+questionId]); // 'foo'
```

Long answer: [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the short and long answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ES5 you can do so with creating new empty object. Here are the steps:

1.create empty object

```
var o = {};
```

2. use brackets to produce the new key on an object - `("object_" + questionId)` - this will force the parser first to evaluate expression in the brackets

3.assign value to a newly added key

```
o[("object_" + questionId)]  = XXX;
```

Then `console.log(o)` will output `{object_0: XXX}`

Comment: Or just store the questionId as a key in the object without the superfluous prefix :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window object (access to global variables only):

```js
var object_0 = { p: 42 },
    questionId = 0,
    key = "object_" + questionId;
document.write(window[key].p);
```

But i suggest to change the data structure to a more concise style:

```js
var questions = { 200: { p: 42 }},
    questionId = 200;
document.write(questions[questionId].p);
```